# How do I change the state to a different object within an array of objects in a Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have a React Redux single page app that displays a car and its available features and updates the total cost of the car according to the features that the user selects. Right now I only have one car object in my reducer . I want to be able to have an array of several car objects and have the app display only the information of the selected car object.  Im thinking all I have to do is add the cars to the initial state in the reducer and then change the state to the selected car on the component , but im having difficulty putting it all together in the reducer and component . Do i make a separate reducer for just the car objects ? Should I list out each individual car in the component i have ?

in the actions file

```
export const ADD_ITEM = "ADD_ITEM";
export const REMOVE_ITEM = "REMOVE_ITEM";
export const CHANGE_CAR= "CHANGE_CAR"

export function removeItem(item) {
  return {
    type: REMOVE_ITEM,
    payload: item
  };
}
export function addItem(item) {
  return {
    type: ADD_ITEM,
    payload: item
  };
}
export function changeCar(car){ 
    return{ 
        type: CHANGE_CAR, 
       payload: car
    };
}
```

Reducer file ( do i add the other car objects to the initial state here?)

```
import {ADD_ITEM,REMOVE_ITEM , CHANGE_CAR}from "../actions"

export const initialState = {
  additionalPrice: 0,
  car: {
    price: 26395,
    name: "2019 Ford Mustang",
    image:
      "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/0AN2V/s1/2019-ford-mustang-bullitt.jpg",
    features: []
  },
  additionalFeatures: [
    { id: 1, name: "V-6 engine", price: 1500 },
    { id: 2, name: "Racing detail package", price: 1500 },
    { id: 3, name: "Premium sound system", price: 500 },
    { id: 4, name: "Rear spoiler", price: 250 },
    { id: 5, name: "Performance Exhaust", price: 800 },
    { id: 6, name: "Intake Upgrade", price: 500 },
    { id: 7, name: "Chrome Rims", price: 200 }
  ]
};

export const featuresReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
       switch(action.type){
          case ADD_ITEM:
          return{
                additionalPrice:state.additionalPrice + action.payload.price,
                car:{
                    ...state.car, 
                    features:[...state.car.features,action.payload]
                },
                additionalFeatures: state.additionalFeatures.filter(feature => feature !== action.payload)
          }
          case REMOVE_ITEM:
              return{
                additionalPrice:state.additionalPrice-action.payload.price,
                  car:{
                      ...state.car, 
                      features:state.car.features.filter(item=>item !== action.payload)
                  },
                  additionalFeatures: [
                    ...state.additionalFeatures,
                    action.payload
                ]
            }
          
        default:
            return state
      }
  }
```

Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux"; 

const Header = props => {
  return (
    <div>
    <strong>
    {props.car.name} 
    </strong>
      <figure className="image is-128x128">
        <img src={props.car.image} alt={props.car.name} />
      </figure>
      <h2>{props.car.name}</h2>
      <p>MSRP: ${props.car.price}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
        car:{
        image: state.featuresReducer.car.image, 
        name: state.featuresReducer.car.name,
        price: state.featuresReducer.car.price
        }
    }
    
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Header)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `initial state` as an array with the default car details and its features. For **eg:**

```
export const initialState = [{
  additionalPrice: 0,
  car: {
    price: 26395,
    name: "2019 Ford Mustang",
    image:
      "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/0AN2V/s1/2019-ford-mustang-bullitt.jpg",
    features: []
  },
  additionalFeatures: [
    { id: 1, name: "V-6 engine", price: 1500 },
    { id: 2, name: "Racing detail package", price: 1500 }
  ]
},
{
additionalPrice: 0,
  car: {
    price: 36395,
    name: "2019 Nissan",
    image:
      "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/0AN2V/s1/2019-ford-mustang-bullitt.jpg",
    features: []
  },
  additionalFeatures: [
    { id: 1, name: "V-6 engine", price: 1500 },
    { id: 2, name: "Racing detail package", price: 1500 },
    { id: 3, name: "Premium sound system", price: 500 },
    { id: 4, name: "Rear spoiler", price: 250 },
  ]
}];
```

Update you `reducer` to return an array and your actions to have **car name** (Or any unique identifier for car) in the payload along with its additional feature details.

Filter the respective car by name and update the details in `reducer` accordingly for your actions.

Comment: how would i make the reducer to change the state  though. If i use an array like above, the current actions wont work in the reducer because the initial state has to be a singular object

Comment: You should alter your current actions a bit as suggested in answer. In reducer, you can use `.filter` on array(state) to find out respective `car` object and update the `additinalFeatures` and `price`. state need not be an **object** all the time. It's depends on our requirement. IMHO array fits best here as per your requirement.